# How to have editable table in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to know is there any way to have editable table in ASP.net like in MVC.
I searched for it but could not find any tutorial or answer, what I found was an asp.net MVC editable table.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a

Is this also possible in simple asp.net?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am [searching for the similar kind of a solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195691/how-to-implement-an-editable-table-in-asp-net-without-using-built-in-edit-updat) Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an editable DataGrid. Here's short tutorial: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1360/add-edit-update-delete-gridview/

Comment: yes i have used the datagrid, but if there is any way to make it possible in simple asp.net table or even in repeater?

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the click label to make editable, then you just need to make Template Columns and bind the click event of the labels to make the row editable.