# An editable dynamic table in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, grid

I could implement an editable table with know number of columns eg in:
[How to have editable table in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243747/how-to-have-editable-table-in-asp-net)

In my case we have more than 100 tables and I am looking for a generic solution  Where we can pass any table name and Web us should display the database in tabular format. Some thing like edit in sqlserver edit data rows.

I have come across [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/),jqgrid,[web grid](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/10/a-first-look-at-the-asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid/) but they support only tables where we have column names before hand.In my case the columns and the tables will be decided in the run time only.

Answer (score 0):

JQGrid you have to give column names but they are not fixed. Means you can define column names at run time and it will generate column as per the column name you are giving.

Two things can be done in this case, either you give column model and column names from server and push it as string or json array. 
Or create is on client side based on the data you are getting.

I am using the first option to do almost similar thing. Please let me know if any more details are required. Same is true for every other library available there.